# Could we add custom function query in Azure search like Solr FunctionQueries

Tags: customization, azure-cognitive-search, function-query

I have building search engine of a website by Azure search and need to add some complex logic rule in searching. It's can be written easily in programming languages: C#, python...but hard in query syntax. I saw Solr has feature like FunctionQueries and elastics search can run a python script. How about Azure search service?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported.

Maybe there is a different way to enable your scenario. Feel free to reach out to me at jlembicz at Microsoft com to discus your requirements in detail.